# Combining Rows in an Excel file in R

Tags: r

I have a large excel file where I have 180 columns and 4000 rows. I want to combine some of the rows because most of the cells have an NA value. My first four columns are Metabolite, Mass, RT and RRT. The following columns contain areas for the metabolite peaks with one column containing information about one sample. I want to combine the rows based on the Metabolite name, and the RRT. The rows that are to be combined need to have a RRT value that is 0.05 of each other. The new merged rows need to have all of the original columns including the separate columns for each of the samples. I have tried a few codes but I am having a hard time getting anything to work how I want it to. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried a few codes but I usually end up getting a very short list of metabolites and somehow lose the area columns along the way.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvGz0.png)

Comment: Can you please share some sample data? Also, can you provide more information about how you would like to combine the rows where RRT is within 0.5? For example, you could take the average of all rows to combine them or create a nested dataframe or paste the values for all rows together in one aggregate row

Comment: Also, please share some of the code you have tried and mention why it does not work as you intended

Comment: I have added an image of what my data looks like

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.